# Issue in reading and processing text file using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm an amid new user to VBA and trying to read a text file of big in size. Sometimes text file of some MB's of size too.

The data consists of printed results against some number at different time stamps.

The time stamp where I need to store the values is as follows:

STEP TIME COMPLETED        1.00    ,  TOTAL TIME COMPLETED         1.00

Then the printed data is as follows:

```
90000354   1        -3.9630E-02 -3.5410E-02 -0.2695      0.4523       2.424      0.5630
```

Now, I want to look for the number 90000354 and need to copy and paste these numbers -3.9630E-02, -3.5410E-02 & -0.2695 in to the excel sheet. Right now, I'm using the follow code, but it is giving issues. Please help to fix this issue.

Many thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim text As String, MyData As String, strData() As String, myFile As String, textLine As String

Dim v As Variant

Dim numIde As Long, i As Long

myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Dat Files (*.dat), *.dat")

Open myFile For Input As #1

MyData = Space$(LOF(1))

Do Until EOF(1)

    Line Input #1, textLine

    MyData = MyData & textLine & vbCrLf

Loop

Close #1

strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

numIde = 90000354

For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)

    If InStr(1, strData(i), numIde, vbTextCompare) Then

        Cells(2, 2).Value = Mid(numIde, numIde + 20, 11)

        Cells(2, 3).Value = Mid(numIde, numIde + 32, 11)

        Cells(2, 4).Value = Mid(numIde, numIde + 44, 11)

        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Running the code is ended up with an error as follows:

"Run-time error '54': Bad file mode"

While trying to debug, it is stopping at this code line "Get #1, , MyData"

Comment: Nice question but you need to provide information on where it is giving issues, if you could be more explicit in what error you are getting and when that will help someone to answer

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Gary Evans. I forgot to add the output after running the code. The error is "Run-time error '54': Bad file mode". While trying to debug, it is stopping at this code line "Get #1, , MyData".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get` is for reading binary data, and you want to read text.  Use `Line Input`

Edit:  Updated - this should work better.  Read in each line, then check it.  Saves having to bother with the `split` function that may or may not recognize the vbCRLF, depending on OS etc.

Do something like this:

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim text As String, MyData As String, strData() As String, myFile As String
Dim numIde As Integer
Dim i As Long

numIde = 90000354
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Dat Files (*.dat), *.dat")

Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    If InStr(1, textline, numIde, vbTextCompare) Then
        Cells(2, 2).Value = Mid(textline, numIde + 20, 11)
        Cells(2, 3).Value = Mid(textline, numIde + 32, 11)
        Cells(2, 4).Value = Mid(textline, numIde + 44, 11)
    End If
Loop
Close #1
```

If you prefer the way it was being done, then there was a slightly problem with the code I had previously posted.  It was that it was appending each line of text to a single string, not adding it as a new line, so the `Split()` function wouldn't work.  The updated code here should work.

```
Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, text
    MyData = MyData & text & vbCrLf  '<-need to append the vbCRLF
Loop
Close #1
strData = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)
```

Comment: Thank you. After implementing the modification, now there is no error. But the output is blank. Please help.

Comment: Thank you again @ainwood. I modified the code, but now, a new error as "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" is popping up. If trying to debug, it is pointing out the "If" loop (6th life from the bottom of the code). Kindly check.

Comment: Please update your post with the revised code.  Instr() shouldn't give a subscript out of range error.  And I see an error I put in the Mid code - change 'text' to textline.

Comment: I've updated the code, kindly check. It is giving no output.

Comment: OK - suggest you put a breakpoint on one of the lines starting with "Cells" to prove that it is finding the numIde that you're searching for.  Also:  You are trying to output to "cells", but not telling it which cells.  Qualify it with (for example) `Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2,2).value`.  Secondly, the Mid function is looking for numIde, which is 90000354.  It is doing this via `Mid(numIde, numIde + 20, 11)`, which will search the string **90000354**, and return the characters starting at character number 90,000,354.  I assume you mean something like `mid(strdata(i),len(numIde),11)`

Comment: i.e. the mid function won't work - what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Thank you @ainwood. Now, my problem is solved. The code is working as required.